# Nodejs/Meteor function wasting lot of time listening to email hunter api

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, meteor

I basically have a list of emails that need to be validated by an api.
This api is slow and taking a lot of time to respond.
My server is just idle and wasting time waiting for the api to respond.
How do i make my server serve other requests until I receive data from api?
My function looks like below.

```
for(var patCounter = 0 ;patCounter<patterns.length;patCounter++) {
                var pattern = patterns[patCounter];
                hunterUrl = "https://api.emailhunter.co/v2/email-verifier?email="+pattern+"@"+domain;
                result = HTTP.call('GET', hunterUrl).data.data;
                if(result && result.result=="deliverable"){
                    break;
                }
        }
```

Comment: What is HTTP? what type/library?

Comment: I am using meteor in backend . HTTP is an inbuilt api

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a callback function. Meteor docs state that if you leave it out in the call(as you are doing) the call will block
https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html

```
    for(var patCounter = 0 ;patCounter<patterns.length;patCounter++) {
                        var pattern = patterns[patCounter];
                        hunterUrl = "https://api.emailhunter.co/v2/email-verifier?email="+pattern+"@"+domain;
                        HTTP.call('GET', hunterUrl,function (error, result) {
                          if (!error) {
                           //continue processing here
                         }
                        );

   }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. The reason I am doing a synchronous HTTP call is that I need to check the result of current execution before making the next call.Any other soolutions?

Comment: This is the JavaScript way, you need to do that kind of decision inside the callback

Comment: I think there should be a better way.

Comment: You have to wait for server results, you can't get past that fact. The only choice you have is whether to block waiting for the result. In JavaScript you only have one thread so you don't want to ever block that thread waiting for I/O

Comment: You need to rethink your sequence of events. E.g. If you fire off all the requests one after the other they can run parallel against server and you will get answer back quicker

Comment: Instead of your solution which does the requests in sequence

Comment: I am having a feeling this is nothing more than some JS promise/future concepts I should use in the right manner. Although I can't get past the fact that I need to wait for the result, I can serve other requests(say user 2) until I get back the result

Comment: Exactly, promises and callbacks are similar constructs

Comment: This answer would be great if you could refactor the code to accommodate callback.

Comment: I don't have the code for when you've found the correct one so I put a comment instead

Comment: You could also make use of the synced-cron package https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron to kick off these requests on a regular basis - especially if you wanted to do a small number of requests at a time